# How to resolve a Camel-CXF Web Service client ClassNotFoundException

Tags: web-services, maven, cxf, apache-camel, classnotfoundexception

I'm having a painful time resolving a Camel-CXF ClassNotFoundException.  I've included a sample program exhibiting the problem

You can find the source code at:

git@bitbucket.org:levonk/camel-cxf-example.git

To run the program after checking out the project run:

```
mvn test exec:java
```

Here is the exception stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[cxf://http://www.webservicex.net/globalw... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: cxf://http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetWeather?publishedEndpointUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webservicex.net%2Fglobalweather.asmx&serviceClass=net.webservicex.GlobalWeather.class due to: net.webservicex.GlobalWeather.class
at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:181)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:750)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:1829)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1609)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1478)
at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1446)
at org.apache.camel.main.Main.doStart(Main.java:109)
at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:148)
at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:343)
at com.levonk.app.example.camel.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:17)
... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: cxf://http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetWeather?publishedEndpointUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webservicex.net%2Fglobalweather.asmx&serviceClass=net.webservicex.GlobalWeather.class due to: net.webservicex.GlobalWeather.class
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:508)
at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:62)
at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:108)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:114)
at org.apache.camel.model.FromDefinition.resolveEndpoint(FromDefinition.java:72)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.getEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:90)
at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:861)
at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:176)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.webservicex.GlobalWeather.class
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at org.apache.cxf.common.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.loadClass2(ClassLoaderUtils.java:287)
at org.apache.cxf.common.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtils.java:261)
at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfEndpoint.setServiceClass(CxfEndpoint.java:653)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperty(IntrospectionSupport.java:492)
at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperty(IntrospectionSupport.java:546)
at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperties(IntrospectionSupport.java:434)
at org.apache.camel.util.EndpointHelper.setProperties(EndpointHelper.java:249)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.setProperties(DefaultComponent.java:258)
at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfComponent.createEndpoint(CxfComponent.java:84)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:119)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:488)
... 25 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with the maven Exec Maven plugin not picking up the classes generated from your WSDL at runtime.

The correct way to do structure this sort of thing in Maven is to separate your WSDL -> Java generation out into a seperate project, and add a dependency on that project in your cxf-client. This way, the generated code is just a dependency like any other. See https://github.com/FuseByExample/smx-ws-examples for an example of how to do this.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to help me out!